# Laravel: Node modules not available

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

In Laravel 5.7.10, I've installed a few node modules, but I can't seem to work out how to make them available to my client-side JS. To use OpenLayers as an example, these are the steps I've followed:

```
npm install ol --save
npm install
npm run dev
```

My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.7",
    "ol": "^5.3.1",
    "ol-popup": "^4.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.7",
    "ol": "^5.3.1",
    "ol-popup": "^4.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7"
  }
}
```

I have this in resources/js/app.js:

```
/* OpenLayers dependencies */
const pbf = require('pbf');
const pixelworks = require('pixelworks');
const rbush = require('rbush');

require('ol');
```

In public/js/app.js I can see the OpenLayers core code has been loaded into there.

I have the following at the end of my php page:

```
<script src="{!! asset('js/app.js') !!}"></script>
```

In the client-side JS I'm running, I use the following function to check if a module is present:

```
function moduleAvailable(name) {
    try {
        require.resolve(name);
        return true;
    } catch(e){}
    return false;
}

function checkForModule(module_name) {
    if (moduleAvailable(module_name)) {
        console.log("Module '"+module_name+"' loaded via Mix!");
    } else {
        console.log("Module '"+module_name+"' not detected");
    }
}
```

When I run the above function using 'ol' as the module_name, I always get "Module 'ol' not detected" - and the same happens for all of the other modules listed as dev-dependencies in package.json.

I can't help but think I'm missing something really simple, but after a couple of days of trying to figure this out I just can't crack it. What else should I check?

Comment: what is the moduleAvailable method do? Can you add details?

Comment: Sorry about that - I've added the moduleAvailable function to the code now.